# Height 100% on container breaks links / buttons for Android 4.0, but fine on 2.3, 3 and 4.1

Tags: android, browser, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Building a larger html/css/javascript app, so I can't really post relevant code snippets.

It works in the browser, and on iOS, and on all other versions of Android, except 4.0. Have tested and confirmed the issue in the emulator and on a device.

I've cleared off the tranform3d's, the user-selects, and the overflow-scrolling:touches from the CSS.

Clue:

When I trace the events, they always seem to target my container, not the items I touched.

Any ideas?

Ok, so I have discovered that a parent container has a 'height:100%' on it. Removing this enables the clicks, but kills the scrolling. Argh.

It works fine on the Chrome Browser on ICS, just not the default browser...

Answer (score -1):

Try to add document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){}); to the body, and keep it can be called as soon as possible

Comment: I'm not sure what this would accomplish. Can you outline your theory?